# Bootstrap: CSS media queries not overriding original CSS

Tags: css, media-queries

I need to have separate nav bars depending on if the site is viewed on mobile or desktop. I have two nav bars designed (I know this would be easier using JS but this needs to be a CSS solution).

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top pb-mobile-nav">
...

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top pb-main-nav">
...
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
.pb-main-nav { 
    display:block;
}

.pb-mobile-nav  { 
    dispaly: none;
}
```

and when we get down to iPhone Plus sizes

```
@media screen and (max-width: 414px) {

    .pb-main-nav { 
        display:none;
    }

    .pb-mobile-nav  { 
        dispaly: block;
    }
}
```

.pb-main-nav accepts the new display of none, but .pb-mobile-nav does not accept the display of block, it remains none. I don't understand why one works and the other doesn't (per specificity rules) but I now have no menu. This is not optimal. : )

Any ideas of how to get this CSS to work?

Comment: Can you once try to use all the classes for css. I mean this way: .navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top.pb-main-nav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A error in your code:

```
.pb-mobile-nav  { 
        dispaly: block;
}
```

Change to:

```
display: block;
```

Comment: In my defense, I'm on vacation. : ( 

Thanks for the extra set of eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to

```
display: block !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if its not recommended, using `!important` you can force which properties should be applied. Moreover, using the same CSS selectors (class in that case), specificity is the same for each each styling that is applied. However, make sure that the order of the CSS selectors is correct, because the final style will be applied.